# express session not persisting from page to page

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I am trying to save sessions, but when I do the session doesn't exist on the next request.

When I send an ajax request to `/login` I set the session with `req.session.username` and then I send back an object that says `{success:true}`. I then refresh the page, and if the username exists on the session I display the user page otherwise I display the main page.

Everytime I refresh the page at `/` It always shows the login even after I send the request to `/login` and set the session. Why is the session not saving?

```
let express = require('express')
let sessions = require('express-session')
let bodyParser = require('body-parser')
let app = express()

app.use(sessions({
  secret: 'connection-id',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
}))

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.username) {
    res.render('pages/home')
  } else {
    res.render('pages/index')
  }
}).post('/login', (req, res) => {
  if (req.xhr) {
    req.session.username = req.body.username
    res.send({ success: true })
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(500)
  }
})
```

Client Side:

```
let response = await fetch('/login', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: new FormData((document.getElementById('login-form'))).toJson()
})

let json = await response.json()
if (json.success) {
  window.location.href = '/'
}
```

When I make the Ajax Request, I get the following header back:

```
set-cookie:connect.sid=s%3At25S_TmjwL6vVkhyJ9LuKIyy4EH1LTcy.Zu4fBpMibfjmMofxQI5K%2FmgAYHWFqQf3x8HPzcQbDH4; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 23 Jul 2017 15:29:26 GMT; HttpOnly
```

[image: Cookie]

### Edit

So after commenting everything out in my code and slowly uncommenting and testing the lines, I found that this does not work:

```
req.session.username = req.body.username // body.username Contains a string
```

However, this does work:

```
req.session.username = 'Billy'
```

I am not sure why it is doing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you saving the cookie, token, whatever is generated client side and is it being sent with each request

Comment: No I am not. I am using fetch to send the information.

Comment: Check the console see if the cookie was saved/sent.

Comment: A cookie called `connect.sid` does get created, and the value looks encrypted. I added a picture.

Comment: Looking at express-session code(index.js line 96) that is the default name of the cookie. So it is correct.

Comment: Okay I have found the issue but don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured out my issue, it had nothing to do with the server but the ajax `fetch()` request.

I needed to add the option `credentials: 'include'` to it like so:

```
let response = await fetch('/login', {
  method: 'post',
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: new FormData(document.getElementById('login-form')).toJson()
})
```